# pageController with multiple viewControllers

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add a pagecontroller with multiple viewControllers. I've started by creating a contentView in interfacebuilder and embedded a pageController in it. Then i've added below code, but it does not seem to show anything?

```
   let initialViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0)
    self.pageViewController?.setViewControllers([initialViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

**PAgeViewController Extension**

```
var viewControllerIdentifiers = ["BottomNoLogo", "TopNoLogo"]



extension CameraViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let currentText = viewController.restorationIdentifier

    var currentIndex = viewControllerIdentifiers.indexOf(currentText!)
    if currentIndex == viewControllerIdentifiers.count - 1 {
        return viewControllerAtIndex(0)
    } else {
        return viewControllerAtIndex(++currentIndex!)
    }
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let currentText = viewController.restorationIdentifier

    var currentIndex = viewControllerIdentifiers.indexOf(currentText!)
    if currentIndex == 0 {
        return viewControllerAtIndex(viewControllerIdentifiers.count - 1)
    } else {
        return viewControllerAtIndex(--currentIndex!)
    }
}

func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> UIViewController {

    let contentViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(viewControllerIdentifiers[index])

    return contentViewController!
}


}
```

Comment: What's contentViewController showing (debug) in viewControllerAtIndex function?

Comment: Did `viewControllerAtIndex` correctly instantiate anything?

Comment: self.pageViewController is returning nil

Comment: So you found the bug. `let contentViewController = storyboard?.instantiate...` is not working correctly.

Answer (score -1):

The page view controller really just provides the dots:  you've still got to add the controllers' views as subviews of the parent view and manage the scrolling.  There are lots of examples out there.  See http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/, for example.

Comment: First of all your example is in objective-c and secondly this is not using a containerView